# Why is it not possible to assign contrasts using with() or transform() in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been trying to learn more about environments in R. Through reading, it seemed that I should be able to use functions like with() and transform() to modify variables in a data.frame as if I was operating within that object's environment. So, I thought the following might work:

```
X <- expand.grid(
    Cond=c("baseline","perceptual","semantic"),
    Age=c("child","adult"),
    Gender=c("male","female")
)

Z <- transform(X,
    contrasts(Cond) <- cbind(c(1,0,-1)/2, c(1,-2,1))/4,
    contrasts(Age) <- cbind(c(-1,1)/2),
    contrasts(Gender) <- cbind(c(-1,1)/2)
)
str(Z)
contrasts(Z$Cond)
```

But it does not. I was hoping someone could explain why. Of course, I understand that `contrasts(X$Cond) <- ...` would work, but I'm curious about why this does not.

In fact, this does not work either [EDIT: false, this does work. I tried this quickly before posting originally and did something wrong]:

```
attach(X)
    contrasts(Cond) <- cbind(c(1,0,-1)/2, c(1,-2,1))/4
    contrasts(Age) <- cbind(c(-1,1)/2)
    contrasts(Gender) <- cbind(c(-1,1)/2)
detach(X)
```

I apologize if this is a "RTFM" sort of thing... it's not that I haven't looked. I just don't understand. Thank you!

[EDIT: Thank you joran---within() instead of with() or transform() does the trick! The following syntax worked.]

```
Z <- within(X, {
    contrasts(Cond) <- ...
    contrasts(Age) <- ...
    contrasts(Gender) <- ...
  }
)
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What's your intended result? And where is `with` in this question?

Comment: @Thomas I meant that I tried both with() and transform() in the spot where I had transform in the code above---should have been more clear about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transform` is definitely the wrong tool, I think. And you don't want `with`, you probably want `within`, in order to return the entire object:

```
X <- within(X,{contrasts(Cond) <- cbind(c(1,0,-1)/2, c(1,-2,1))/4
                contrasts(Age) <- cbind(c(-1,1)/2)
                contrasts(Gender) <- cbind(c(-1,1)/2)})
```

The only tricky part here is to remember the curly braces to enclose multiple lines in a single expression.

Your last example, using `attach`, works just fine for me.

`transform` is only set up to evaluate expressions of the form `tag = value`, and because of the way it evaluates those expressions, it isn't really set up to modify attributes of a column. It is more intended for direct modifications to the columns themselves. (Scaling, taking the log, etc.)

The difference between `with` and `within` is nicely summed up by the Value section of `?within`:

> **Value** For with, the value of the evaluated expr. For within, the modified object.

So `with` only returns the result of the expression. `within` is for modifying an object and returning the whole thing.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Can you say a couple words about the difference between with() and within()? And why transform() is way off? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification in your edit, super clear.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @Jornan that `within` is the best strategy here, I will point out it is possible to use `transform` you just need to do so in a different way

```
Z <- transform(X,
    Cond = `contrasts<-`(Cond, value=cbind(c(1,0,-1)/2, c(1,-2,1))/4),
    Age = `contrasts<-`(Age, value=cbind(c(-1,1)/2)),
    Gender= `contrasts<-`(Gender, value=cbind(c(-1,1)/2))
)
```

Here we are explicitly calling the magic function that is used when you run `contrasts(a)=b`. This actually returns a value that can be used with the `a=b` format that `transform` expects. And of course it leaves `X` unchanged.

The `within` solution looks much cleaner of course.